# Angular2 RC5 default route being AppComponent

Tags: angular, router

I have an AppComponent that holds main navigation bar and router outlet for the rest of the application. Now, by convention, this is my starting point of Angular2 application.

I also have routes component which will hold my routes(currently is empty).

What happens is the following: when I start the application, I get an error in console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''
```

I am aware of why is this happening. My question is: is it possible to have an AppComponent as your default route? Or do I have to have a separate component that will hold the initial UI and register it in routes component with an empty(default) path and then inject it into AppComponent?

Comment: Can you show your code for this?

Comment: There is no code needed, this was more of a general question. @micronyks provided an answer down below in the comment: "router-outlet must have one view in it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** : ***You have to make sure that default route is set when router-outlet is used***.

---

> is it possible to have an AppComponent as your default route

what do you mean by default route? You can have **AppComponent** as your **bootstrap component** which comes to the screen first. **AppComponent** may contain **router-outlet** for other component.

According to your routes, you can inject default route/view/component into `router-outlet`.

So when you run app, you'll have **AppComponent** with (let's say) **HomeComponent**.

**So Answer is YES**

Look at this plunker. It has **AppComponent**, it loads **HomeComponent(Feature Component)** as default. Moreover, AppComponent has two **router links**.

https://plnkr.co/edit/aw3BZxUwsjnkVqhZI4GW?p=preview

Comment: I think you didn't understand. In your plunker you have a HomeComponent that is being called when your route matches an empty route ( ' ' ). I don't want that, I want it without that

Comment: route-outlet must have one view in it.

Comment: So, in fact, I have to create a "HomeComponent" like you did in plunker that will be displayed when "default" or an empty route is active.

Comment: If you want, you can repost your comment as an answer, I will accept it.